# How to update column value based on another value in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below data frame

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 10 |
| Feb | 20 |
| Mar | 30 |
| Apr | 20 |

Required Output - I want to check for March from A and get its corresponding value from B and add that value to remaining B values to update the dataframe using pandas

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 40 |
| Feb | 50 |
| Apr | 50 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one line, pandas-style, using `set_index()`:

```
df = df.set_index('A').pipe(lambda x: x.assign(B=x['B'] + x.loc['Mar', 'B'])).drop('Mar').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     A   B
0  Jan  40
1  Feb  50
2  Apr  50
```

Or in multiple lines (not so pandas-style):

```
df['B'] += df.loc[df['A'] == 'Mar', 'B'].iloc[0]
df = df[df['A'] != 'Mar']
```

Or a third and slightly shorter way:

```
tmp = df.set_index('A').T
df = (tmp.pop('Mar').iloc[0] + tmp.T['B']).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value corresponding to 'Mar', add that value to the rest of the df, then drop the row containing 'Mar'

```
df.loc[df['A'] != 'Mar','B'] += df.loc[df['A'] == 'Mar', 'B'].values
df = df[df['A'] != 'Mar']
```

Result:

```
>>> df
     A   B
0  Jan  40
1  Feb  50
3  Apr  50
```